# Classpath issue with Intellij Idea 2016.1.1 and Gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

After a recent upgrade in Idea I now get a ClassNotFoundException in code that just a day ago was working perfectly.

If i run gradle in the command line it works perfectly, but if I run in Idea it fails with the ClassNotFoundException.

I've googled the problem and it seems that others have similar issues, but the solutions proposed for them don't seem to work for me.

I get that it's probably a classpath and/or gradle issue with the latest version of Idea, but I cannot see exactly what the issue would be since I've only recently moved over to both Idea and Gradle from Eclipse and Maven.  My general Java experience is very good.

The full stack trace is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Shape
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Shape
    at uk.co.redfruit.gdx.skyisfalling.listeners.PlayButtonListener.changed(PlayButtonListener.java:18)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ChangeListener.handle(ChangeListener.java:28)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor.notify(Actor.java:181)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor.fire(Actor.java:146)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button.setChecked(Button.java:123)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$1.clicked(Button.java:91)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener.touchUp(ClickListener.java:89)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener.handle(InputListener.java:58)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.touchUp(Stage.java:354)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglInput.processEvents(LwjglInput.java:316)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:210)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:123)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Shape
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 12 more
```